# How to exchange authorization code for token on google oauth using php form

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I get the **authorization code** few days, but I always keep getting **HTTP 400 error** when trying to exchange it for an access/refresh token by my test code. I am Google for few days, but still can not find the way to fix it. Any one can help me to fix it, thanks.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$redirect_url = "http://.../callback_google.php";
$client_id=".....";
$client_secret=".....";
$code=$_GET['code'];
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?';
$postField = array ('grant_type=authorization_code',
                    'client_id='.urlencode($client_id),
                    'client_secret='.urlencode($client_secret),
                    'redirect_uri='.urlencode($redirect_url),
                    'code='.urlencode($code) );
$postField = implode('&', $postField);

$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                 CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
                 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                 CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
                 CURLOPT_POST => true,
                 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postField) );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But I get error message

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
Via: 1.1 PROXY
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 06:04:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

JSON response is

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

Any one could help me to solved it, thanks.

Comment: This issue is fixed, it was caused by array, and http_build_query.  Change to **$postField = 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id='.urlencode($client_id).
&client_secret='.urlencode($client_secret).'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($redirect_url).'code='.urlencode($code);**, and remove function call **http_build_query**.

Comment: i can't able to get access token though i am copy pasting your code.. please suggest me your solution or paste your working code in a link

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> This issue is fixed, it was caused by array, and `http_build_query`. Change to:
>   `$postField = 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id='.urlencode($client_id). &client_secret='.urlencode($client_secret).'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($redirect_‌​url).'code='.urlencode($code);` , and remove function call `http_build_query`.